# How to delete rows under a condition from first n rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to delete some rows under some specific condition from first n rows of a Data Frame.
For example i have a data frame

```
        Table_Number.130.ID_HOUR Date     Time_.EST.
1                   137     480  365       1600
2                   340       0  4         1612
3                   340       0  365       1619
4                   340       0  87        1657
5                   340       0  365       1700
6                   129      60  365       1700
7                   340       0  365       1703
8                   340       0  96        1709
9                   340       0  365       1740
10                  340       0  365       1755
11                  129      60  365       1800
12                  340       0  365       1804
13                  340       0  365       1811
14                  340       0  365       1817
15                  340       0  365       1825
16                  340       0  365       1833
17                  340       0  365       1839
18                  340       0  365       1848
19                  340       0  365       1857
20                  129      60  365       1900
```

I want to delete from first 10 rows where Date >350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>% filter(!(Date > 350 & row_number() %in% 1:10))
dt2
   Table_Number.130. X.ID_HOUR Date Time_.EST.
1                340         0    4       1612
2                340         0   87       1657
3                340         0   96       1709
4                129        60  365       1800
5                340         0  365       1804
6                340         0  365       1811
7                340         0  365       1817
8                340         0  365       1825
9                340         0  365       1833
10               340         0  365       1839
11               340         0  365       1848
12               340         0  365       1857
13               129        60  365       1900
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "        'Table_Number.130.'' ID_HOUR' Date     'Time_.EST.'
1                   137     480  365       1600
                 2                   340       0  4         1612
                 3                   340       0  365       1619
                 4                   340       0  87        1657
                 5                   340       0  365       1700
                 6                   129      60  365       1700
                 7                   340       0  365       1703
                 8                   340       0  96        1709
                 9                   340       0  365       1740
                 10                  340       0  365       1755
                 11                  129      60  365       1800
                 12                  340       0  365       1804
                 13                  340       0  365       1811
                 14                  340       0  365       1817
                 15                  340       0  365       1825
                 16                  340       0  365       1833
                 17                  340       0  365       1839
                 18                  340       0  365       1848
                 19                  340       0  365       1857
                 20                  129      60  365       1900",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rbind`

```
dt <- read.table(text = "        'Table_Number.130.'' ID_HOUR' Date     'Time_.EST.'
1                   137     480  365       1600
                 2                   340       0  4         1612
                 3                   340       0  365       1619
                 4                   340       0  87        1657
                 5                   340       0  365       1700
                 6                   129      60  365       1700
                 7                   340       0  365       1703
                 8                   340       0  96        1709
                 9                   340       0  365       1740
                 10                  340       0  365       1755
                 11                  129      60  365       1800
                 12                  340       0  365       1804
                 13                  340       0  365       1811
                 14                  340       0  365       1817
                 15                  340       0  365       1825
                 16                  340       0  365       1833
                 17                  340       0  365       1839
                 18                  340       0  365       1848
                 19                  340       0  365       1857
                 20                  129      60  365       1900",
                 header = TRUE)

rbind(subset(dt[1:10,], subset = Date > 350), dt[11:nrow(dt),])
```

Comment: I know the OP did not provide a reproducible example. But if you want, feel free to use my `read.table` code to create the dataset and modify your solution with the OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

My solution using just the base packages. A little bit of a hack but it works fine.

```
x[-x[x$Date>=350,]$Table_Number[1:10],]
```

Comment: But table number is a different field it is not the index of the data frame

Comment: Right but for the purposes of the question it'll work just the same. You could pull out and use the index if you wanted here I just used Table_Number because it was there.